# Changing Joomla plugin settings from an article

Tags: joomla2.5

I am an amateur at Joomla. I have been trying to insert a [photo gallery plug-in](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/photo-gallery/12768) in one of my articles in Joomla 2.5.
The code in the documentation looks like this :

```
{artsexylightbox path="images/img_folder"}{/artsexylightbox}
```

But when I type this, It appears as plain text in the article. However, another code is working.

```
{loadposition myposition}
```

What exactly is going on?
I now need to change path parameter. How can I do that from within the article?

Comment: In order to use plugin you need to make sure it is enabled in Extensions -> Plugin Manager -> Art Sexy Lightbox Lite.

Comment: I enabled it in the plugin manager. Its working fine with default settings. I just want to know how I can change the path of the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the extension developers site.

**Art Sexy Lightbox Lite**

"Free - this is free version of extremely popular Art Sexy Lightbox extension. Lite Edition comes as module only."

Since plugin is not available u will have to create multiple gallery modules.In module manager create two **Modules**  with different *position* and *Path to images folder* properties.simply load it using `{loadposition myposition}`.

If u want to use plugin then try the [SIGE](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/content-photo-gallery/13762) plugin

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I gave up on this plugin and configured Simple Image Gallery plugin. It worked like a charm